# how to fetch values in hash array ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have written small ruby code to get publish stats, code is following

```
begin
  response = conn.get("api/queues")
  statistics = JSON.parse(response.body)

  statistics.each do |qDetails|
    payload = "#{qDetails["name"]}"
    if payload != "aliveness-test"
      puts "#{qDetails["message_stats"]["publish"]}"          
    end             
  end      
rescue Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed => e
  puts "Connection failed"
end
```

but i get this error in return

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

message_stats json would be like this

```
{"deliver_get_details"=>{"rate"=>0.0}, "deliver_get"=>1357, "ack_details"=>{"rate"=>0.0}, "ack"=>1357, "redeliver_details"=>{"rate"=>0.0}, "redeliver"=>0, "deliver_no_ack_details"=>{"rate"=>0.0}, "deliver_no_ack"=>0, "deliver_details"=>{"rate"=>0.0}, "deliver"=>1357, "get_no_ack_details"=>{"rate"=>0.0}, "get_no_ack"=>0, "get_details"=>{"rate"=>0.0}, "get"=>0, "publish_details"=>{"rate"=>0.0}, "publish"=>1400}
```

what's the issue?

Comment: when i change the code to this 
puts "#{qDetails["message_stats"]}" it works but whole json would print

Comment: On what line do you get the error? Are you sure `"message_stats"` is always filled in, because that would explain immediately.

Comment: @nathanvda i want to get publish data so when i add ["publish"] i get that error.

Comment: @nathanvda message_stats not always filled.

Answer (score 2):

For ruby > 2.3, you can use `dig`:

```
qDetails.dig("message_stats", "publish")
```

This will safely access `qDetails["message_stats"]["publish"]`

The error you're getting is probably because `qDetails["message_stats"]` is nil, so calling `[]` on it doesn't work

Comment: @frodo why unaccept the answer then, and even more to accept a poor rephrasing of this one?

Comment: @Geoffroy it seems not fair indeed. I suggest you to flag the other copied answer, and explain precisely what happened.

Comment: (btw, the same user posted another copy-paste answer on a question of mine)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ruby-fetch](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/fetch) method to get the data from hash where you are unsure about existence of a key. You can also set default value to return unlike `dig` returns nil if value not found

```
qDetails["message_stats"].fetch("publish", "default_value")
```

Another way would be like by using safe navigation operator (`&`):

```
qDetails["message_stats"]&.[]('publish') # Return nil if not found
```